# How to disable session resumption in pyOpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

The [Tripple Handshake Issue](https://secure-resumption.com/) was disclosed lately. Wether disabling session resumption will mitigate this or not, is a topic for [another question](//security.stackexchange.com/q/53287/36761). Let's assume I want to disable it for whatever reason (basicly my paranoia).

To disable this in C, it seems like one should use this:

```
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF);
```

Can someone please confirm this?

But how to do this in pyopenssl?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with pyOpenSSL 0.14 this is possible:

```
from OpenSSL.SSL import TLSv1_2_METHOD SESS_CACHE_OFF, Context, Connection

ctx = Context(TLSv1_2_METHOD)
ctx.set_session_cache_mode(SESS_CACHE_OFF)

conn = Connection(ctx, ...)
```

Earlier versions of pyOpenSSL do not expose these APIs.

If you also need to turn off session tickets then:

```
from OpenSSL.SSL import OP_NO_TICKET

...

ctx.set_options(OP_NO_TICKET)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please confirm this?

I believe Dr. Henson answered this over at the [OpenSSL User Mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.openssl.users/wU2hEVYyUGI/2pbWTWGrv4cJ).

> > the attack described in https://secure-resumption.com/ breaks also tls
> >     channel binding tls-unique RFC 5929.
> >
> > I would still like to use tls-unique for channel binding as defined in
> >     SCRAM (RFC 5802). Can OpenSSL be used for channel binding and protect
> >     against this attack if the session caching is disabled?
> >
> > SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF)
> >
> > Is it necessary to disable resumption using a different function?
>
> You'd also need to disable session tickets too.
>
> Note the initiial phase of the attack requires that the attacker
>   possess a private key and certificate the client trusts. I'd be
>   interested to know how that could happen under your circumstances.

So, according to Dr. Henson, you also need to call `SSL_CTX_set_options` with `SSL_OP_NO_TICKET`. See the OpenSSL docs at  
[SSL_CTX_set_options(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html).

I don't know how to do it in Python, though.