# Could not disable session resumption requested by OpenSSL client

Tags: authentication, openssl, session

I'm developing `SSL` mutual authentication in android to connect to a `HTTPS` website using OpenSSL library. I want to disable session resumption requested by client in OpenSSL; In other words, it is expected from the client not to sent previous session ID in the "Client Hello" message, but it sends.

I tried using `SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF)`, but nothing changed.

Can anyone help me disable session reuse?

Thanks

Comment: You're attempting to disable on the server or the Android client?

Comment: I want to disable from client-side.

Comment: Are you setting the cache mode of the `SSL_CTX` prior to the first connection using that ctx, or afterwards?

Comment: [You also need to turn off session tickets.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22382205/3714897)

Comment: It's set prior to the first connection